# How can I prevent a Tableview from snapping back to the top?

Tags: ios, xcode

Currently in the app I am making, I have a tableview. The issue is that when I try to scroll, it always snaps back to the top rather than letting me scroll through the entire list. I assume it is simply a setting in the storyboards, however I haven't been able to find it. Here is a video of the issue:

https://youtu.be/wSUb9ofFASM

Additionally, here are my scroll settings:

[image]

Please let me know if you have any idea as to how to fix this so that the user can freely scroll through the items in the tableview without always being sent back to the top.

Comment: Remove bottom constraint and drag table view at the top (around 50 pixels) and then reassign bottom constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove equal height and add bottom constraint of table view to 0